# Matlab function to calculate

Tags: matlab

How can I input the two functions from this task in matlab ? 
 
A voltage peak in a circuit is caused by a current through a resistor. 
[image]

The energy E which is dissipated by the resistor is: 
[image]

 Calculate E if 
[image]

**This is my final solution:**

```
function E = calculateE(i0,R,t0)
syms t;
f = i0*exp(-t/t0) * sin(2*t/t0);
E = int(R*f*f,0,inf);
end
```

**Question: how can I input the above functions in matlab to calculate the result?**

Comment: What do you want to calculate? $E$?

Comment: yes, but I probably don't want to use the final formula.. but do it all in matlab

Comment: MATLAB is not well-suited for symbolic computation unless you use the symbolic toolbox, but even then this is not a very good problem for that. It is still completely unclear whether you want MATLAB to be computing the integral or what. What are your inputs/outputs?

Comment: the inputs are i0, R, and t0.. and I want to calculate E , integral of the function

Comment: So if $I_0=100$, $t_0=0.01$, $R=0.5$, you want to compute $100^2*0.01*0.5/5$? What is the problem computing that exactly?

Comment: actually the solution is irelevant , how can I input the functions i(t) and the integral in matlab?

Comment: You either need to use the symbolic toolbox or choose a numerical quadrature routine. There is no built-in function for generalized integration in MATLAB.

Comment: can you show an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a MATLAB function like

```
function E = calculateE(i0,R,t0)
  % The function i(t) 
  function y = i(t)
    y = i0 .* exp(-t/t0) .* sin(2.*t/t0); 
  end  

  function y = intFunction(t)
    y = R * i(t).^2;
  end

  % Calculate energy 
  E = integral(@intFunction,0,Inf);
end
```

Comment: Undefined function or method 'integral' for
input arguments of type 'function_handle'. And you missed R and i^2(t) in calculation of E

Comment: @IulianRosca, what version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: Matlab : 7.12.0.635

Comment: I am using 8.1.0.  "integral" must not be available in your older version, so you'll have to do the integration yourself.

Comment: int doesn't work either...

Comment: No, int is not a MATLAB function.

Comment: there is actualy a int function

Comment: No, there are integer types, but the "int" function you're referring to is probably the MuPAD function (not MATLAB).

Comment: help int
 --- help for char/int ---

 INT    Alternative entry to the symbolic integration function.
    INT(F,...) is the same as int(sym(F),...).

Comment: @IulianRosca, yes you are right.  Maybe you can use this function.

Comment: but it still doesn't accept a function_handle

Comment: Consider upgrading your MATLAB.  Or use Octave which has functions such as "quad"

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I am misunderstanding your question.  Put that function code in a file named calculateE.m in the directory that you are running MATLAB in.  On the MATLAB command line, or in another MATLAB function file, the line myE = calculateE( myi0, myR, myt0); will call the function using values myi0, myR, myt0 and return the result myE.